# How to check the permissions of a user with a site collection?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

I want to check if a user is a site collection administrator of a particular site collection. When I go through the member functions I see two functions

```
site.CheckForPermissions(SPReusableAcl acl, SPBasePermissions perms)
site.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPReusableAcl acl, SPBasePermissions perms)
```

But how to use them? What is `SPReusableAcl`? How can I relate `SPUser` and `SPReusableAcl`?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you know about the [.isSiteAdmin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.issiteadmin.aspx) Property? You can check if the current user is admin by using

```
SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin
```

Also check out the `SPWeb.SiteAdministrators` collection.

Actually there are some nice suggestions on [how to check if a user is site collection administrator here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/15d082e0-6514-4a5b-9647-6f1778bd0dde).

Comment: So just checking the permissions against the RootWeb is same as checking against the site collection?

Comment: Well yes and no, if your site collection administrators are ONLY added to the site you won't find them on the RootWeb - check the link. Easier is going for the `SPWeb.SiteAdministrators` collections and check whether your wanted user is in there.